# Docker build from Dockerfile with more memory

Tags: docker, memory, docker-build, neural-mt

**How to `docker build` from Dockerfile with more memory?**

This is a different question from this [Allow more memory when docker build a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913110/allow-more-memory-when-docker-build-a-dockerfile)

When installing the software natively, there is enough memory to successfully build and install the [`marian` tool](https://github.com/marian-nmt/marian)

But when building the Docker image using the `Dockerfile`
https://github.com/marian-nmt/marian/blob/master/scripts/docker/Dockerfile.cpu , it fails with multiple memory exhausted errors

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

[out]:

```
Step : RUN cmake $MARIANPATH && make -j
 ---> Running in 4867d166d17a
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Cannot find CUDA libraries. Compiling without them.
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   timer
--   iostreams
--   python
--   thread
--   chrono
--   regex
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found Python
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.7.4") 
-- Git version: 5abc774
-- Found SparseHash: /usr/include  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /marian/build
Scanning dependencies of target fast_align
Scanning dependencies of target extract_lex
Scanning dependencies of target libcnpy
Scanning dependencies of target atools
Scanning dependencies of target libyaml-cpp-amun
[  2%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/extract_lex/CMakeFiles/extract_lex.dir/exception.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/extract_lex/CMakeFiles/extract_lex.dir/utils.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/fast_align/CMakeFiles/fast_align.dir/src/ttables.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/fast_align/CMakeFiles/fast_align.dir/src/fast_align.cc.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/extract_lex/CMakeFiles/extract_lex.dir/extract-lex-main.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/CMakeFiles/libcnpy.dir/cnpy/cnpy.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/fast_align/CMakeFiles/atools.dir/src/atools.cc.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/fast_align/CMakeFiles/atools.dir/src/alignment_io.cc.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/regex_yaml.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/scanner.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/convert.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/stream.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/memory.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/node.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/directives.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/null.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/emitfromevents.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/singledocparser.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/emitterstate.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/scantag.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/simplekey.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/binary.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/parser.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/nodeevents.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/emit.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/exp.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/nodebuilder.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/scanscalar.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/emitter.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/tag.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/scantoken.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/ostream_wrapper.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target libcommon
[ 37%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/node_data.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/contrib/graphbuilder.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/emitterutils.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/contrib/graphbuilderadapter.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/parse.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/scorer.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/git_version.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/base_matrix.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/sentence.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/config.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/utils.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/vocab.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/filter.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/god.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/exception.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/search.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/hypothesis.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/translation_task.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/printer.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/sentences.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/history.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/logging.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/processor/bpe.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/output_collector.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/types.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/loader.cpp.o
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

And eventually it leads to:

```
src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/build.make:254: recipe for target 'src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/loader.cpp.o' failed
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make[2]: *** [src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/cpu/decoder/encoder_decoder.cpp.o] Error 1
src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/cpu/decoder/encoder_decoder.cpp.o' failed
[ 79%] Built target libcnpy
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/build.make:326: recipe for target 'src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/printer.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/common/printer.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:340: recipe for target 'src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/amun/3rd_party/yaml-cpp/CMakeFiles/libyaml-cpp-amun.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:182: recipe for target 'src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/amun/CMakeFiles/libcommon.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:110: recipe for target 'src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Looking at the `docker build --help`, there are options to control memory usage:

```
$ docker build --help

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile

Options:
      --build-arg list             Set build-time variables (default [])
      --cache-from stringSlice     Images to consider as cache sources
      --cgroup-parent string       Optional parent cgroup for the container
      --compress                   Compress the build context using gzip
      --cpu-period int             Limit the CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
      --cpu-quota int              Limit the CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
  -c, --cpu-shares int             CPU shares (relative weight)
      --cpuset-cpus string         CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --cpuset-mems string         MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --disable-content-trust      Skip image verification (default true)
  -f, --file string                Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
      --force-rm                   Always remove intermediate containers
      --help                       Print usage
      --isolation string           Container isolation technology
      --label list                 Set metadata for an image (default [])
  -m, --memory string              Memory limit
      --memory-swap string         Swap limit equal to memory plus swap: '-1' to enable unlimited swap
      --network string             Set the networking mode for the RUN instructions during build (default "default")
      --no-cache                   Do not use cache when building the image
      --pull                       Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image
  -q, --quiet                      Suppress the build output and print image ID on success
      --rm                         Remove intermediate containers after a successful build (default true)
      --security-opt stringSlice   Security options
      --shm-size string            Size of /dev/shm, default value is 64MB
  -t, --tag list                   Name and optionally a tag in the 'name:tag' format (default [])
      --ulimit ulimit              Ulimit options (default [])
```

But I couldn't figure out the correct syntax of where exactly to put the `-m` option -_-|||

It isn't before the Dockerfile:

```
# Before Docker file.
$ docker build -m 4g Dockerfile.cpu -t ibot-cpu .

"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

It isn't after Dockerfile before -t

```
# Before -t
$ docker build Dockerfile.cpu -m 4g -t ibot-cpu .

"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

It isn't after -t before the local path

```
# Before local path
$ docker build Dockerfile.cpu -t ibot-cpu -m 4g .

"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

It isn't after the local path at the end too...

```
# At the end...
$ docker build Dockerfile.cpu -t ibot-cpu . -m 4g

"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

**How to `docker build` from Dockerfile with more memory?**

My docker version:

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   4845c56
 Built:        Wed Apr  5 18:45:47 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is not something about order. The Dockerfile must be specified with `-f`

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.cpu -t ibot-cpu -m 4g .
```

However, take into account that by default docker does not limit the container memory. It can take the whole free memory.

As I can see that you are on OSX, which runs docker over a Linux VM. Configure the max memory clicking the whale icon in the task bar. It's 2GB by default.

For further information please see my other answer:
[How to assign more memory to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container/44533437#44533437)